# Allow objects to pass through an object while also detecting the collision in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a ball to pass trough an empty object but also send back a message to debug window. But I don't have a clue how to do this or where to start, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am sorry I have no code to show as an example, however I have been able to get a collision detection or to allow the object pass through the empty object one at a time but never both. I have used `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnCollionEnter`.

Comment: You would have more answers there: http://answers.unity3d.com

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc Of course but SO is IMO the technically superior system. I don't like it if an accepted answer gets 0 reputation, sorry but what's that. Timestamps of old questions are sometimes a mess ... My accounts were messed up during the migration in 2011 ... So you may understand why some people prefer to stay at SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Put a `Collider` (e.g. a `SphereCollider`) on your empty object, and set its `Is Trigger` to `true`. Now you can use `OnTriggerEnter` in your script (attached to the empty object) as you expected.

```
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var collider = other.gameObject;
        // Do something...
        Debug.Log(collider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your GameObject's collider a Trigger on the Editor. Go to the editor and add a collider to your GameObject, then make it a Trigger.

C# Code

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("I hit something: " + other.gameObject);
}
```

Javascript

```
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) 
{
    Debug.Log("Hey I hit you: " + other.gameObject);
}
```